# Cloudflare -> EC2 -> EC2 522 Errorr

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-web-services, cloudflare

I'm having an issue where Cloudflare is pointing at an EC2 instance through SSL and it's redirecting traffic to another EC2 instance through HTTP. It's been working properly until yesterday where sometimes the connection seems to fail and I'm getting a 522 error.

According to Cloudflare support, it seems one or two of Cloudflare's IPs are having >50% loss ratios, but the others are working fine.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you redirecting traffic to another EC2 instance, or is CloudFlare? Are you proxying or redirecting? If CloudFlare has failed there's not much anyone outside CloudFlare can do to fix it, other than tell you to turn off CloudFlare if it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was nginx getting swamped by the amount of calls and it only had one worker available. I set worker_processes to auto and it worked just fine. I also had to change worker_rlimit_nofile to 50k due to the amount of calls I was getting.